# mySQL php AJAX data not inserting from AJAX js file

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Trying to create a comment application on my website.
Data is not inserted properly although it "posts" to the AJAX javaScript file.
Here is the main page: http://micromedia.vaniercollege.qc.ca/home/nortonb/php/

Works:

You can insert a comment using an already registered user: sn@dot.com pass: sn
(note: alert is from js/ajax.js)

- include on main page to db/comments.php to display comments
- include to js/ajax.js file
- on submit passes info to comment_ins.php through ajax.js file

  `<input name="submit" type="button" class="indent" value="add your comment" onclick="loadXMLDoc('db/comments_ins.php')">`

Does not work:

If the user's email does not exist in the db, comment_ins.php displays another form with firstName and lastName inputs.

This uses the same ajax.js file but now db/comments_add_user.php to insert the new user, and then insert their comment in a related table.

(note: the parameters are being passed to the ajax.js file, but the info is not submitted in the database)

I have tried:
-hard coding the data in db/comments_add_user.php works

-passing the info from a regular form but still using js/ajax.js works

http://micromedia.vaniercollege.qc.ca/home/nortonb/php/c_test.htm

Thanks in advance.
Bruce

Here is the guts of my index.php file:

```
<h4>Comments</h4>
    <article id="comms">

    <form name="intro" action="" method="post">
        <fieldset> 
            <legend>Add your comment</legend> 
            <label for="comment">
                Comments:<br /><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="5" class="indent"></textarea><br /> 
            </label>   
            <label for="email">
                Email:<br /><input name="email" id="email" type="text" size="32" class="indent"/>
                <span id="emailMessage"></span>
            </label><br />

            <label for="password">
                Password:<br /><input name="password" id="password" type="password" size="32" class="indent"/>
                <span id="passwordMessage"></span>
            </label><br />

                <input name="submit" type="button" class="indent" value="add your comment" onclick="loadXMLDoc('db/comments_ins.php')">

        </fieldset> 
    </form> 
    <?php include("db/comments.php"); ?>

    </article>
```

And here is the js/ajax.js file:

```
// JavaScript Document
function loadXMLDoc(xmlDoc){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("comms").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }


    var commentValue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("comment").value);
    var emailValue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("email").value);
    var passwordValue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("password").value);

    var parameters="comment="+commentValue+"&email="+emailValue+"&password="+passwordValue;
    //if a new user then add these things
    if(document.getElementById("firstName")){ 
        var firstNameValue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("firstName").value);
        var lastNameValue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("lastName").value);
        //parameters are formatted in name=value pairs
        var parameters="firstName="+firstNameValue+"&lastName="+lastNameValue+"&comment="+commentValue+"&email="+emailValue+"&password="+passwordValue;

    }
    alert(xmlDoc + " parameters: "+parameters);
    xmlhttp.open("POST", xmlDoc, true);//true = asynchronous
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(parameters);

}
```

Here is the db/comments_ins.php (which seemingly works fine)

```
<?php
    //comments_ins.php adds new comments to the database
    //if the user has already registered, the comment is displayed
    //else a form is displayed for new users keeping the comment and email from the original comment form

    //to do list:
    // ??? should I combine this into comments.php?
    // ??? should I separate the forms into a separate .php file with a conditional for new users?
    //fix scrolling issue? 
    //jQuery? AJAX?
    include  'includes/mysqli_connect.php';
    //get the posted info
    echo("comments_ins.php<br />");
    if(isset($_POST["comment"])){
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
        $hashedPassword = hash(sha256,$password);
        $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
        $comment = trim($_POST["comment"]);
        //see if user exists
        $query = "select * from users where email = '$email' and password = '$hashedPassword' limit 1";//adding limit 1 speeds up the query on big tables
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        //get response from database    
        if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)){
            $numrows = $result->num_rows;
            //echo ('found '.$numrows.' user: <br>'. $firstName.'<br>');
            while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {    
                $userArray[] = array('userID'=>$row->userID,
                    'firstName'=>$row->firstName, 
                    'lastName'=>$row->lastName,
                    'email'=>$row->email
                );//line breaks for readability
            }
            $verifiedUserID = $userArray[0]['userID'];//get userID for insert below
            //echo("\$verifiedUserID: ".$verifiedUserID);
        }else{
            // This means the query failed
            echo("errr...");
            echo $mysqli->error;
        } 

        //if the user already exists...
        if($numrows > 0){//should add something if numrows > 1 i.e. for duplicate users!!
            //echo("user is registered <br />");
            $commentQuery="INSERT INTO comments (comment, userID) VALUES ('$comment', '$verifiedUserID')";
            $commentResult = mysqli_query($link, $commentQuery);
            //get response from database
            $commentNum =  mysqli_affected_rows($link);
            echo(mysqli_error());
            //echo ('<br />inserted '.$commentNum.' record: <br />'. $comment.'<br />');
            include("comments.php");
        }else{//if the user does not exist
            echo("Please register to display your comment: <br />");
            ?>
            <form name="intro" action="" method="post">
                <fieldset> 
                    <legend>Register to share your comment:</legend> 
                      <label for="firstName">
                        First Name: <br />
                        <input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" class="indent" size="32" />
                        <span id="firstMessage"></span>
                      </label>
                      <br /> 
                      <label for="lastName">
                        Last Name:<br />
                        <input name="lastName" id="lastName" type="text" class="indent" size="32" />
                        <span id="lastMessage"></span>
                      </label>
                      <br />  
                      <label for="email">
                        Email:<br />
                        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" size="32" class="indent" value="<?php echo($email); ?>"/>
                        <span id="emailMessage"></span>
                      </label>
                      <br />
                      </label>
                      <label for="password">
                        Password:<br />
                        <input name="password" id="password" type="password" size="32" class="indent"/>
                        <span id="passwordMessage"></span>
                      </label>
                      <br />
                      <label for="comment">
                        Edit your comment?<br />
                        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="5" class="indent"><?php echo($comment); ?></textarea>
                      </label> <br /> 
                      <input name="submit" type="submit" class="indent" value="join us" onclick="loadXMLDoc('db/comments_add_user.php')"/>
                    <p class="note">(Of course we will keep your stuff private!!)</p>
                </fieldset> 
            </form> 
        <?php   
        }//end else($numrows <=0)

        //close connection
        mysql_close($link);
    }
    ?>
```

And here is the comments_add_user.php file (which doesn't work when called from the js/ajax.js file but does when called from

```
<?php
    include  'includes/mysqli_connect.php';
    //get the posted info
    echo("hi mom");
    $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];//"Two";//
    $lastName = $_POST["lastName"];//"Two";//
    $password = $_POST["password"];//"Two";//
    $hashedPassword = hash(sha256,$password);
    $email = $_POST["email"];//"Two";//
    $comment = $_POST["comment"];//"Two";//
    echo($firstName." from comments_add_user.php<br>");

    //since email does not exist, 
        $query="INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, password, email) VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$hashedPassword', '$email')";
        $result=mysqli_query($link, $query);
        //get response from database
        $num=  mysqli_affected_rows($link);
        echo(mysqli_error());
        echo ('inserted '.$num.' record: <br>'. $firstName.'<br>');
    //** add error checking ?!?

    //get the userID for the new user
        $userQuery = "select userID from users where email = '$email' limit 1";//adding limit 1 speeds up the query on big tables
        $userResult = mysqli_query($link, $userQuery);

        //get response from database    
        if($userResult = mysqli_query($link, $userQuery)){
            $numrows = $userResult->num_rows;
            echo ('found '.$numrows.' user: <br>'. $firstName.'<br>');
            while ($row = $userResult->fetch_object()) {
                $userArray[] = array('userID'=>$row->userID);//line breaks for readability
            }
            $newUserID = $userArray[0]['userID'];//get userID for insert below
            //echo("\$verifiedUserID: ".$verifiedUserID);
        }else{
            // This means the query failed
            echo("errr...");
            echo $mysqli->error;
        } 

    //now insert the comment
        $commentQuery="INSERT INTO comments (comment, userID) VALUES ('$comment', '$newUserID')";
        $commentResult=mysqli_query($link, $commentQuery);
        //get response from database
        $commentNum=  mysqli_affected_rows($link);
        echo(mysqli_error());
        echo ('inserted '.$commentNum.' record: <br>'. $comment.'<br>');


    echo('<br><a href="comments_display.php">display all comments</a><br />');
    //close connection
    mysql_close($link);

    ?>
```

Comment: Nice SQL injection holes you've got there... be a shame if someone drove a truck through them into your server.

Comment: Thanks Mark B. I knew I should have plugged them before posting.

Comment: No more trucks. Added some slashing and stripping. Plan to add prepared statements once I get this working. Thanks again Mark B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused with where your problem is right now

So might need you to recap things for me so i can help you..

Other than that, i noticed that you have `<form name="intro" action="" method="post">`

I just want to make sure that you got this right, `action=""` means actually pointing to index.php and not db/comments_ins.php

I don't know if that's what you really want to happen...

EDIT: I see what's happening, you click add comment, the registration form appears, you click join us, it DOES call AJAX but then the page is refreshed because the `<input>` is of type `submit` which means that this submits the form when you click it
So that makes your page reload... what you need is to change that line in comment_ins.php to :

```
<input name="submit" type="button" class="indent" value="join us" onclick="loadXMLDoc('db/comments_add_user.php')"/>
```

After i did that change, i am getting the output from the add user file...

Comment: Thanks @DanyKhalife
Problem is that AJAX does not work when I try to register users.
New form is created by db/comments_ins.php if email (and password) don't exist or don't match. 

You are correct: action="" points back to the index.php (or database.php file in this case). It is the onClick event that $_POSTs the info via: onclick="loadXMLDoc('db/comments_ins.php')

Comment: so your registration form appears but when the user clicks "Join Us" nothing happens ?
EDIT: ok i see, i'll load that up on my server to debug it for you..

Comment: ok i updated my answer, let me know if that solves your problem and vote it up in case it does :)

Comment: Yeah!!!
@Dany, thank you so much.
In the immortal words of Roberto De Vicenzo...
"What a stupid I am!" (ps. can't vote it up yet... not enough rep)

Comment: hehe my pleasure :) we all have moments like that
ah i guess you can accept the answer with the tick tho? or does that need rep too :S ? btw lol i just noticed you go to a CEGEP right next to where i live, what are the odds :D

Comment: Crazy... it's a small world. And now that I have more comments... my rep is > 15 I am able to vote it up and accept the answer.
Plus, I have updated all the php scripts to OOP style and prepared statements.